# why do I loose information when I reload an angularJS page

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I have an angular/meteor app.  I have a route that's a config page and when I go there and enter my configuration and navigate back to the display route, all my configurations are saved.  When I refresh the page, they're gone.

service

```
    app.service('Config', function(){
    var localEquipment = [];

    this.getEquipment = function(){
        return localEquipment;
    }

    this.setEquipment = function(equipment){
        localEquipment = equipment
    }
})
```

route

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('display', {
        url: '/display',
        templateUrl: 'display.ng.html',
        controller: 'DisplayController',
        controllerAs: 'display'
      })
      .state('config',{
          url: '/config',
          templateUrl: 'config.ng.html'
      });
```

so i go to config and setEquipment through my Config service and navigate back to display(using a link created in my app), and my localEquipment is set.  as soon as I refresh the page, it's set back to `[]`

Comment: JavaScript variables aren't persistent.  when you refresh the page, you are initiating a request as if this were the first time the page was loaded.  If you want your items to stay permanently, or be visible to multiple users, you have to provide some sort of persistence on the server side (database or the like).  If they are settings for each user, then local storage/cookies would be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using local storage with an if check to see if it had already been set.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using AngularUI Router to its fullest potential. When you start using [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) these types of problems will go away. Bottom line is that you should be resolving `Equipment` in both `config` and `display` states.